# Custom pop up or spinner for android

Tags: android

i found a design in IOS that i really like but i cant figure out how to do it in android i have tried doing a custom spinner and am having a hard time with it and i thought of using a pop up but i need to be able to put clickable button in the pop up, so i think a spinner is my best change. I am going to post a picture of what i am trying to accomplish, specifically on the little half box on the top of the drop down! Thanks would really Appreciate some help thanks!!!! ![enter image description here][1] Also i have seen this in Android as well so i know it can be done. https://i.stack.imgur.com/nVZ3H.png

Comment: This is the image i am trying to replicate.http://i.imgur.com/L1ftrSU.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's action you showed in your image is called QuickAction, there are many tutorials on how to create one:

1. Try the [NewQuickAction](https://github.com/lorensiuswlt/NewQuickAction) lib, it has a number of modes, and one of them will give you exactly the same layout as your sample image. [Here](http://www.londatiga.net/it/how-to-create-quickaction-dialog-in-android/)'s a quick tutorial for using the library. Have used this lib for 2 years and worked quite well.
2. [This tutorial](http://capdroid.wordpress.com/2011/07/28/android-quick-action-menu/) offers another method to accomplish the same thing, worth checking out as well.

Answer (score 0):

You can use OptionMenu. Refer to this [link](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/menus.html)!

Comment: Thanks this will be us full, do you know how i can do the triangle on top of it?

Comment: I don't think you can do this with Menus in Android. I think you should use something different, like a custom Dialog, but i never did that so i can't help you. BTW if my answer was good for you, please accept it.